# How do I find assumptions on M such that M gets compact?

Tags: compactness

I have a problem understanding the meaning of this question:

> Consider a set $M$ endowed with the discrete, the indiscrete or the cofinite topology, under which assumptions on M does this yeld a compact space?

As I understood this, I first endow $M$ with the discrete topology, then with the indiscrete and lastly with the cofinite. But in my opinion with the indiscrete topology we don't need any assumptions on M right? But how do I find assumptions with the other two topologies?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you taken sets of various sizes, given them these topologies, and then thought about whether or not they are compact?

Comment: Adding to @Randall's comment, why do you think that for the indiscrete topology you don't require any assumptions? If that approach is correct, can we have a similar approach for the other topologies?

Comment: Now I'm not sure anymore if we don't require any assumptions. I wanted to use the proposition which says that M is compact iff for every collection of closed subsets of M with empty intersections we can find finitly many of them which intersects also trivially, but I don't think this is useful

Comment: So do you think its better working with the definition? Because then if I look again at the indiscrete topology, then the only open cover of M is M itself, and then we can't find an open subcover, thus M would never be compact, but this is also strange

Comment: No, in that case EVERY open cover is already finite.  It is trivially compact.

Comment: Try this exercise:   prove that any space that has only a finite number of open sets must be compact.

Comment: Ah so I was right that with the indiscrete topology we don't need any assumptions to be compact.

Comment: Hmm okey, but then with your exercise I now that M has to be finite with the discrete topology, then it is also compact right? But can I use this fact also for the cofinite topology, since in there a subset is open if the complement is finite

Comment: On the first, yes, you have the right idea.  In the second, you have to be more careful.  You need to look at examples under the cofinite topology:  do it with $M=\{1,2\}$ and again with $M = \mathbb{R}$.  The argument is a little subtle:  in the latter, there are an infinite number of open sets.

Comment: Okey I will try it, maybe I will write here again if I don't get it.

Comment: Is it right that if M is finite then the cofinite topology is equal to the descrete topology, therefore compact. Now we only need to consider the infinite case i.e. $card(M)=\infty$. But how do i handle this case?

Comment: You are making good progress.  If you have an open cover of an infinite $M$, how many points will a single open set miss?

Comment: sorry I don't get it. a single open set will miss infinitly many points?

Comment: No. In the cofinite topology a single open set can miss only finitely many points.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Because that's the definition of the topology.